# Enabling Duplicates in WHERE … IN?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use a simple query to decrement a value in a table like so:

```
UPDATE `Table`
SET `foo` = `foo` - 1
WHERE `bar` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

This works great in examples such as the above, where the `IN` list contains only unique values, so each matching row has its `foo` column decremented by 1.

The problem is when the list contains duplicates, for example:

```
UPDATE `Table`
SET `foo` = `foo` - 1
WHERE `bar` IN (1, 3, 3, 3, 5)
```

In this case I would like the row where `bar` is `3` to be decremented three times (or by three), and `1` and `5` to be decremented by 1.

Is there a way to change the behaviour, or an alternative query that I can use where I can get the desired behaviour?

I'm specifically using MySQL 5.7, in case there are any MySQL specific workarounds that are helpful.

**Update**: I'm building the query in a scripting language, so feel free to provide solutions that perform any additional processing prior to running the query (perhaps as pseudo code, to be as useful to as many as possible?). I don't mind doing it this way, I just want to keep the query as simple as possible while giving the expected result.

Comment: Where does your list come from? Is it an embedded query, do you have three rows where `bar` = 3, or one?

Comment: Also, is it not `set foo = foo - 1` instead of `set foo - 1`? Or is it the alternate way of writing I am unaware about?

Comment: What does `SET foo - 1` do?

Comment: @vivek_23 you're absolutely right, that's just a typo on my part, I've corrected my original post!

Comment: @DerrickMoeller I'm building the query in PHP so I have full access to the list if a solution requires that, though it may be best to keep it as some kind of pseudo code.

Answer (score 2):

If you can process your original list first to get the counts, you could dynamically construct this kind of query:

```
UPDATE `Table`
SET `foo` = `foo` - CASE `bar` WHEN 1 THEN 1 WHEN 3 THEN 3 WHEN 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
WHERE `bar` IN (1, 3, 5)
;
```

*Note: the ELSE is just being thorough/paranoid; the WHERE should prevent it from ever getting that far.*

Answer (score 0):

There is an example might be beneficial for your purpose:

```
create table #temp (value int)
create table #mainTable (id int, mainValue int)

insert into #temp (value) values (1),(3),(3),(3),(4)
insert into #mainTable values (1,5),(2,5),(3,5),(4,5)

select value,count(*) as AddValue
into #otherTemp
from #temp t
group by value

update m
set mainValue = m.mainValue+ ot.AddValue
from #otherTemp ot
inner join #mainTable m on m.id=ot.value

select * from #mainTable
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little tricky, but you can do it by aggregating first:

```
update table t join
       (select bar, count(*) as factor
        from (select 1 as bar union all select 3 as bar union all select 3 as bar union all select 3 as bar union all select 5
             ) b
       ) b
       on t.bar = b.bar
    t.foo = t.foo - bar.factor;
```